# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error when checking : expected flatten_1_input to have shape [null,7,7,512] but got array with shape [1,224,224,3]

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow.js, transfer-learning, tensorflowjs-converter

I am using the concept of transfer learning to classify my image, I have reused the code mentioned at https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-from-pre-trained-models-f2393f124751

the model is working well for my data(https://www.dropbox.com/s/esirpr6q1lsdsms/ricetransfer1.zip?dl=0) in my jupyter notebook, but before testing the model, I am reshaping the image.

But when I wanted to run the same model in the browser using TensorFlow, I used tfjs.converters.save_keras_model to save my model.

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
import tensorflowjs as tfjs
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

img_width, img_height = 224, 224  # Default input size for VGG16

conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet', 
              include_top=False,
              #input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
              input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

# Extract features
import os, shutil
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
train_size, validation_size, test_size = 148, 27, 31

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
batch_size = 16
train_dir = "ricetransfer1/train"
validation_dir = "ricetransfer1/validation"
test_dir="ricetransfer1/test"
#indices = np.random.choice(range(len(X_train)))

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
   #sample_count= X_train.ravel()

    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 7, 7, 512))  # Must be 
    equal to the output of the convolutional base
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))
    # Preprocess data
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                        target_size=(img_width,img_height),
                                        batch_size = batch_size,
                                        class_mode='binary')
    # Pass data through convolutional base
    i = 0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
return features, labels

train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, train_size)  
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(validation_dir, validation_size)
test_features, test_labels = extract_features(test_dir, test_size)


from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers

epochs = 1

 ricemodel = models.Sequential()
 ricemodel.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(7,7,512)),)
 ricemodel.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_dim=(7*7*512)))
 ricemodel.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
 ricemodel.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
 ricemodel.summary()

 ricemodel.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(),
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['acc'])

 import os
 history=ricemodel.fit(train_features, train_labels,
                epochs=epochs,
                batch_size=batch_size, 
                validation_data=(validation_features, validation_labels))

path='\vgg'
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(ricemodel, path)
```

The TensorFlowjs code is

```
 $(document).ready()
{
  $('.progress-bar').hide();
}
$("#image-selector").change(function(){
let reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(){
    let dataURL = reader.result;
    $("#selected-image").attr("src",dataURL);
    $("#prediction-list").empty();
}
let file = $("#image-selector").prop('files')[0];
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});


$("#model-selector").change(function(){
loadModel($("#model-selector").val());
$('.progress-bar').show();
})

let model;
async function loadModel(name){
model=await tf.loadModel(`http://localhost:8081/${name}/model.json`);
$('.progress-bar').hide();
}


$("#predict-button").click(async function(){
let image= $('#selected-image').get(0);
let tensor = preprocessImage(image,$("#model-selector").val());

let prediction = await model.predict(tensor).data();
let top5=Array.from(prediction)
            .map(function(p,i){
return {
    probability: p,
    className: IMAGENET_CLASSES[i]
};
}).sort(function(a,b){
    return b.probability-a.probability;
}).slice(0,5);

$("#prediction-list").empty();
top5.forEach(function(p){
$("#prediction- 
 list").append(`<li>${p.className}:${p.probability.toFixed(6)}</li>`);
});

});


function preprocessImage(image,modelName)
{
 let tensor=tf.fromPixels(image)
.resizeNearestNeighbor([224,224])
.toFloat();//.sub(meanImageNetRGB)

 if(modelName==undefined)
 {
    return tensor.expandDims();
}
else if(modelName=="vgg")
{
    let meanImageNetRGB= tf.tensor1d([123.68,116.779,103.939]);
    return tensor.sub(meanImageNetRGB)
                .reverse(2)
                .expandDims();
}
else if(modelName=="mobilenet")
{
    let offset=tf.scalar(127.5);
    return tensor.sub(offset)
                .div(offset)
                .expandDims();
}
else
{
    throw new Error("UnKnown Model error");
}
}
```

Error Message in the browser after loading the model in the tensorflowjs, I get the below error(I can see the error message in the web development console)

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error when checking : expected flatten_1_input to have shape [null,7,7,512] but got array with shape [1,224,224,3]

Is there any way to solve the issue, can I reshape the image before loading to the browser?

I tried all the possible option but I am stuck now.

I have already checked the possible solutions on the stackoverflow. How can I run classification model on the browser?

Comment: Can you please add to the question your js code ?

Comment: @edkeveked I have updated the tensorflowjs code, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are creating a completely new model `ricemodel` which looks like a fully connected layer and save it as a standalone model without the convolutional base below (VGG in your case). This is why your model has an input layer shaped [,7,7,512] (feature vector) and not [,224,224,3] (raw image data).

To solve this you need to first load the VGG model with its weights pre-trained (for example "imagenet"), pop off the top layer and then add your `ricemodel` on top. Finally save the combined new model and export it to tfjs.

Comment: In my code, am I not adding add the rice model on top? any suggestion about how it can be done?

Comment: Please see the answer @edkeveked posted. It explains very nicely how you add the convolutional layers from VGG

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by the answer of [@andyPotato](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779967/uncaught-in-promise-error-error-when-checking-expected-flatten-1-input-to-h/57780279#57780279), you need to convert the feature extractor model as well to js.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import save_model

#download model 
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', 
          include_top=False,
          input_shape=(width, height, 3)) # tune parameters

#save the model 
save_model(
    model,
    "vgg.h5",
    overwrite=True,
)
```

Convert VGG feature extractor to js

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras \
                       path/to/my_model.h5 \
                       path/to/tfjs_target_dir
```

Now use both model for inference in js

```js
model1 = await tf.loadModel(`/url/of/vgg/converted/model.json`);

featureExtracted = await model1.predict(image)

model2 = await tf.loadModel(`/url/of/sequential/model/model.json`);

prediction = await model2.predict(featureExtracted)
```

Comment: the code work well for the vgg, I think I am doing the same, but when I load my own data then its give an error, any suggestion?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error when checking : expected flatten_1_input to have shape [null,7,7,512] but got array with shape [1,224,224,3]

Comment: Are you able to predict using the js code of vgg16 ? If yes, what is the output shape of the prediction ?

Comment: with the random image, with a random image I get 5 different classes web site, website, internet site, site:0.905993
analog clock:0.003217
tape player:0.001998
nematode, nematode worm, roundworm:0.001950
screen, CRT screen:0.001264

Comment: I was talking about the tensor shape.What is the output of the following `console.log(featureExtracted.shape)` ?

Comment: Hello, I don't have any featureExtracted variable, how can print it in console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198938/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-durgesh-nandini).